# Recursive function to return the line between ancestor and successor

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a recursive function that returns the line between ancestor and successor if one exists. The function takes ancestor, successor and the dictionary of children and their parents as arguments. The code I currently have works on some occasions but not with all, so there must be something still missing from it. I've currently tried to do it with list where i add the people's names but I need to somehow print them out one by one as a result in the end. This is what I have and the examples. The first 4 work but 3 last don't. When looking at the first example, basically what it need to return is

```
Lucia
Adele
Sam
John
```

```
table = {'John': ('Sam', 'Mary'),
            'Mary': ('Konstantin', 'Marie'),
            'Rita': ('Sam', 'Mary'),
            'Simon': ('Sam', 'Mary'),
            'Marie': ('Carl', 'Liz'),
            'Sam': ('Joseph', 'Adele'),
            'Adele': ('Johannes', 'Lucia'),
            'Konstantin': ('Viktor', 'Jelena'),
            'Joseph': ('August', 'Emma'),
            'Viktor': ('Nikolai', 'Maria')}

def return_line(ancestor, successor, table, line = []):
    if successor in table:
        parents = table[successor]
        if ancestor in parents:
            if ancestor not in line:
                line.append(ancestor)
            if successor not in line:
                line.append(successor)         
        else:
            successor_1 = parents[0]
            successor_2 = parents[1]
            return_line(ancestor, successor_1, table)
            if line == []:
                return_line(ancestor, successor_2, table)
            else:
                ancestor = line[-1]
                return_line(ancestor, successor, table)            
    else:
        return
    if line != []:
        return line
    else:
        return("Doesn't exist")

print(return_line("Lucia", "John", table))
print(return_line("Marie", "Adele", table))
print(return_line("Maria", "Mary", table))
print(return_line("Emma", "Rita", table))

print(return_line("Nikolai", "John", table))
print(return_line("Jelena", "John", table))
print(return_line("Carl", "Mary", table))
```

Answer (score 0):

One simpler implementation without passing around mutable arguments:

```
def line(ancestor, successor, table):
    if ancestor == successor:
        return [successor]
    if successor not in table:
        return  # no line exists
    for parent in table[successor]:
        anc_line = line(ancestor, parent, table)
        if anc_line:
            return anc_line + [successor] 

line("Lucia", "John", table)
# ['Lucia', 'Adele', 'Sam', 'John']
line("Marie", "Adele", table)
# None
line("Maria", "Mary", table)
# ['Maria', 'Viktor', 'Konstantin', 'Mary']
line("Emma", "Rita", table)
# ['Emma', 'Joseph', 'Sam', 'Rita']
line("Nikolai", "John", table)
# ['Nikolai', 'Viktor', 'Konstantin', 'Mary', 'John']
line("Jelena", "John", table)
# ['Jelena', 'Konstantin', 'Mary', 'John']
line("Carl", "Mary", table)
# ['Carl', 'Marie', 'Mary']
```

**Base cases:**
1. `ancestor == successor`:  one person constitutes singleton line
2. `successor not in table`: No more information about this person's parents, so no point in looking any further

**Recurse:**
1. find a line from the ancestor to either parent
2. if it exists, append the person at hand

Comment: Cheers! But how could I instead of returning the list, print out the names separately on new lines because that's what I actually need to return with this function? I just tried to solve it with a list.

Comment: And if the line doesn't exist, it should print out "doesn't exist".